X and Y are N(0,1) with correlation 0.5, what is the probability that X+Y is greater than a number
Suppose $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0, 1)$ with correlation 0.5. What is the probability that X+Y is greater than a certain number $n$ ($P(X+Y>n)$)?
What I am thinking is that I can construct a multivariate normal distribution $f(x,y)$ regarding X and Y. The mean and covariance matrix of $f(x,y)$ would be $[0,0]$ and $[1, 0.5; 0.5,1]$. Then I can do $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{n-x}^{\infty}f(x,y)dydx$ to get the answer. Is this correct?
I know that correlation can be interpreted as the cosine of the angles between two vectors. Is there a way to simplify the question using that?
And what if I want the probability P(X-Y>n)?

Not sure if this helps? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19950

$X$ and $Y$ being normal random variables does not mean that $X$ and $Y$ also enjoy a bivariate normal distribution. And if you change your hypotheses to insist that $X$ and $Y$ are indeed bivariate normal, then the value of the probability that $X+Y$ exceeds $\alpha$ can be found more easily by remembering that $X+Y$ is also a normal random variable whose mean and variance can be computed from the known information, Thus, $P(X+Y>\alpha)$ can be expressed as $1-\Phi(\beta)$ for some $\beta$ whose value you can find in terms of $\alpha$ and the given information.

If the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ follows a bivariate normal distribution, that is,
$$\small
    f(x,y)=
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}
        \right]
      \right)$$
with $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0$, $\sigma_X^2=\sigma_Y^2=1$, $\rho=0.5$; then any affine function of $X$ and $Y$ also has a univariate normal distribution, so $$X+Y\sim \mathcal N (0,1+1+2×0.5×1×1)$$ and the probability is $$a=\mathbb P(X+Y>n)=1-\Phi\left (\frac{n}{\sqrt{3}}\right ).$$
Otherwise, the problem is very challenging and the probability lies in an interval around $a$ obtained by finding two extremal copulas.
